# How to set one move on one line in e.g. texmate?

Tags: chess

A document set by using `texmate` (package) looks good but quite dense. I would like to have only one move on one line, as you get in the older chess package by e.g.:

```
\move e2e4 e7e5  
\move g1f3 b8c6
```

Is there a possibility to get a similar appearance in `texmate`?

Compare this example using texmate to a similar using package chess.

texmateexample.tex:

```
%
% Based on the package documentation:
% http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/texmate/texmate2manual.pdf
%
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{texmate}

\title{Example: Chess with TeXmate}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Game with Diagram of Final Board State}

\whitename{Dubois}
\blackname{Steinitz}
\chessevent{London 1862}
\ECO{C50}
\chessopening{Giucco Pianissimo}

\makegametitle
|1 e4 e5 Nf3 Nc6 Bc4 Bc5 0-0 d6 d3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bh4 g5 Bg3 h5 Nxg5 h4 Nxf7 hxg3 Nxd8 Bg4 Qe1 Nd4 Nc3 Nf3+ gxf3 Bxf3 \resigns|
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\showboard
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

chessexample.tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chess}

\begin{document}

\section*{Game with Diagram of Final Board State}
\subsection*{Dubois -- Steinitz, London 1862}
{\sc Giucco Pianissimo}\medskip

\newgame
\move e2e4 e7e5
\move g1f3 b8c6
\move f1c4 f8c5
\move e1g1 d7d6
\move d2d3 g8f6
\move c1g5 h7h6
\move g5h4 g7g5
\move h4g3 h6h5
\move f3g5 h5h4
\move g5f7 h4g3
\move f7d8 c8g4
\move d1e1 c6d4
\move b1c3 d4f3
\move g2f3 g4f3

$$\showboard$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your choice of editor (TextMate) should have no bearing on the output. In order to help you properly though, we really need a [short MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864), so we can see what packages you use to set your document. It would also be of quite some help if you were able to describe in more detail what your problem is, i.e. the output you get now, and what you would like to see instead.

Comment: @moewe `texmate` is a LaTeX package.

Comment: It's quite difficult to say something without an example with `texmate` syntax.

Comment: Arrghh, my bad, for some reason I thought of the editor TextMate. Sorry...

Comment: You can force a new line in texmate with `\renewcommand\afterb{\\}`. But imho it will be difficult to get a proper "tabular" look with it. If you want this better use skak or xskak.

Comment: @Ulrike, your comment answers my question. \styleC in skak is just what I tried to achieve. If you change your comment to an answer I could mark it as the solution.